# jQuery AJAX CORS request / Content-Type / OPTIONS

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, http-headers, cors

I'm making an AJAX call to an API within another origin. As you know, for CORS requests, if you set Content-Type to application/json, this causes a preflight request (OPTIONS). But the API that I'm calling returns "404 not found" for OPTIONS request. So the actual POST request is not sent.

And of course, if I don't set content-type explicitly, it only sends POST request and I get "400 Bad request", because of the formatting issues.

I have tested this call on Google Chrome Advanced REST Client extension with the same parameters. The content-type is set to "application/json". When I send the request and view the chrome's console, I saw that only the actual POST request is sent and the server returns "200 OK" with the data I actually needed.

Isn't it weird? Am I missing something? Is there a way to send only the POST request in this case?

My AJAX call snippet is like below, nothing special:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: myURL,
        data: JSON.stringify({
            someJSON
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (resp) {
            ...
        },
        error: function (x, y, z) {
            ...
        }
    });
```

Thanks.

Comment: I believe it only does preflight OPTIONS if you set custom headers

Comment: Your need to configure your server to hadle CORS request or use jsonp

Comment: according to W3 specs, setting content-type header also causes this, as I understand. @mplungjan

Comment: @devconcept, yes I know, but what about the Chrome's REST client? How can it send only the POST request and retreive the needed data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution to your problem is to remove the settings of your request that are causing the prefligth to be sended to the server. According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) basically all AJAX and HTTP request methods that can potentially modify data are subject of CORS restrictions.

A *simple method* is one of the following

1. `GET`
2. `HEAD`
3. `POST`

And a *simple header* is one of the following

1. `Accept`
2. `Accept-Language`
3. `Content-Language`
4. `Content-Type` if is one of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, `multipart/form-data` or `text/plain`

In your case you can remove the content-type setting of your ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: myURL,
    // remove content-type and allow jquery to process your data
    data: someData,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (resp) {
        ...
    },
    error: function (x, y, z) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Of course this won't work for complex data objects being sent to the server. In this case you need to configure your server to allow this types of requests by responding to OPTIONS requests responding with the correct headers, usually `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` and `Access-Control-Request-Headers`.

Comment: To be more specific, my question is : How can an application like Chrome's REST client make such a POST request without a preflight request, when the content-type is set to application/json? Removing the content-type setting is not an option for this case, because I get a 400 - Bad request error without it.

Comment: Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy. *The behavior of same-origin checks and related mechanisms is not well-defined in a number of corner cases such as for pseudo-protocols that do not have a clearly defined host name or port associated with their URLs (file:, data:, etc.). This historically caused a fair number of security problems, such as the generally undesirable ability of any locally stored HTML file to access all other files on the disk, or communicate with any site on the Internet*. This might be one possible answer to that.

Comment: @DenizAlpaslan It looks like you have no control over the server you are trying to access. In this case you must conform to the server access rules. CORS plays an important role in application security and you must follow its rules. There are no shortcuts here. Are you sure this endpoint doesn't accept anything other than json? Try to send a form with data  and check the results.